# Default Bleeds/Margins for a Letter

Tags: print-design

I have been asked to make a letter sized document (8.5 in x 11 in) and have not been given any bleeds or margins even though it is for printing. 
Is there a general rule of thumb to follow that most say magazines and publications that use the letter format use for these two measures?

Answer (score 2):

In general for all print pieces . . .

Bleeds should be a minimum of .125" and you want a minimum of .125" margin inside the trim area as a safe zone.

I, personally, use .25" (1p6 picas) for both most of the time.